An operand in the update expression has an incorrect data type for Dynamodb Update Integration with ApiGateway
I cant seen to find out whats wrong here
I have tried changing the path variables still not working, I have also tried to manually set the values for total votes.
        requestTemplates: {
          'application/json': JSON.stringify({
            TableName: props.scoresTable.tableName,
            Key: {
              party: { S: "$input.path('$.partyName')" },
            },
            UpdateExpression: 'set totalVotes = totalVotes + :val',
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
              ':val': {
                N: "$input.path('$.votes')",
              },
            },
            ReturnValues: 'NONE',
          }),
        },```

